# Calling protocols from a framework?

Tags: cocoa, protocols

I am currently using the NinevehGL engine to develop a simple app. This engine has a class called NGLMesh that stores openGL data for an instance of this class. From NinevehGL's documentation for the copyInstance method located at http://nineveh.gl/docs/Protocols/NGLCopying.html it says:

"The NGLCopying is an extension of Cocoa protocol NSCopying.

It defines two basic copying modes to NinevehGL objects:

```
Copy: Makes a new clone, copying all the used memory.
Copy Instance: Makes a new clone, but clonning just the superficial memory."
```

I would like to copy one of my NGLMeshs into a new NGLMesh instance using this method, however Im having a hard time understanding protocols and how to call them. Could someone offer some explanation? The internet has proved to be a little confusing thus far.

From what I gather (although Im most likely wrong) I need to "adopt" the NGLCopying protocol in the class that I want to use it with. I cant seem to find much information on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A protocol is just a list of messages that a class can respond to. Think of it as an extension of the class's `@interface` block, only it can be shared by several classes. If you are just trying to copy another class that already conforms to this protocol (such as NGLMesh), you don't need to do anything special — just do `[yourNGLMeshObject copy]` or `[yourNGLMeshObject copyInstance]`.